# How to avoid re-evaluation of each transformation on pyspark data frame again and again

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a spark data frame. I'm doing multiple transformations on the data frame. My code looks like this:

```
df = df.withColumn ........
df2 = df.filter......
df = df.join(df1 ...
df = df.join(df2 ...
```

Now I have around 30 + transformations like this. Also I'm aware of persisting of a data frame. So if I have some transformations like this:

```
df1 = df.filter.....some condition
df2 = df.filter.... some condtion
df3 = df.filter... some other conditon
```

I'm persisting the data frame "df" in the above case.

Now the problem is spark is taking too long to run (8 + mts) or sometimes it fails with Java heap space issue. 
But after some 10+ transformations if I save to a table (persistent hive table) and read from table in the next line, it takes around 3 + mts to complete. Its not working even if I save it to a intermediate in memory table.
Cluster size is not the issue either.

```
# some transformations
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("test")
df = spark.sql("select * from test")
# some transormations    ---------> 3 mts

# some transformations
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
df.count() #action statement for view to be created
df = spark.sql("select * from test")
# some more transformations  --------> 8 mts.
```

I looked at spark sql plan(still do not completely understand it). It looks like spark is re evaluating same dataframe again and again.

What I'm i doing wrong? I don have to write it to intermediate table.

Edit:  I'm working on azure databricks 5.3 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11)

Edit2: The issue is rdd long lineage. It looks like my spark application is getting slower and slower if the rdd lineage is increasing.

Comment: Can't say without seeing either of actual code, environment setup and data

Answer (score 2):

You should use caching.

Try using

```
df.cache
df.count
```

Using count to force caching all the information.

Also I recommend you take a look at [this](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/delta-cache.html) and [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching)